# Is there a way to use the Fingerprint reader authentication for sudo and other situations, today is only useful at the login

Tags: sudo, fingerprint-reader

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with the XPS 13 Plus 9320

Answer (score 0):

- Run `sudo pam-auth-update`
- Select "Fingerprint authentication"
- Choose "OK"

IIRC it is immediate, but you may need to log out and in again for it to take effect.

I am also supposing that libpam-fprintd is installed by default.